# Which main steps should I consider in order to successfully use a VAE for Anomaly Detection?

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, variational-autoencoder, anomaly-detection, word2vec

I am thinking about using the variational autoencoder model for anomaly detection . I have an Android Logs dataset. As the logs generated are a representative of time series type of data I thought about using the VAEs with an architecture involving LSTMs in the encoder and decoders. As far as what I know about the basics of the working of the autoencoder models , given a sequence size say n , during learning/training phase n-1 entries are used to generate a representation/prediction of the nth entry (log in this case) and then reconstruction error is minimized by the model.

How could I approach including the preprocessing steps and any specific architecture for the VAE model that would result in higher accuracy ? I was also thinking about converting the logs into word embeddings using Word2Vec and then using them as input for the VAE model. Also suggest improvements to my approach .

Comment: Could you please check the question in the title is your actual question? If not, feel free to edit your post again ;) Could you also clarify what would be an anomaly in this case? What do you expect the model to detect as an anomaly.